# Juniper SRX 240 Routing Configuration

Tags: routing, juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-srx

I am working with a Juniper SRX 240 as an aggregation routing device, it connects a Desktop (Workstation) environment over an access switch port to several (4) server environments behind Cisco Layer 2 switches which are connected via trunk ports to the Juniper SRX. Hence

Laptop <-- access port --> Juniper SRX 240 <-- trunk port --> Cisco Layer 2 <-- trunk port --> Brocade Switch <-- access port --> Servers

I have configured the necessary RVIs for the VLANs, static routes for the VLANs and security policies and host-inbound-traffic etc. I can ping from the laptop to the RVIs only, on the Juniper CLI I can ping the laptop and can also ping the server gateways on the Brocade switch (Via the Trunk port over the Cisco switch).

My problem is this, I cannot ping from the laptop to the Servers hanging off the brocade switch. I am unsure what is causing this, do I need another security policy for the different VLANs residing on the Brocade switch?

```
    version 12.1X45.5;
system {
    root-authentication {
        encrypted-password "encrypted-password"; ## SECRET-DATA
    }
    name-server {
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.8.8;
    }
    services {
        ssh;
        telnet;
        xnm-clear-text;
        web-management {
            http {
                interface vlan.0;
            }
            https {
                system-generated-certificate;
                interface vlan.0;
            }
        }
        dhcp {
            router {
                192.168.1.1;
            }
            pool 192.168.1.0/24 {
                address-range low 192.168.1.2 high 192.168.1.254;
            }
            propagate-settings ge-0/0/0.0;
        }
    }
    syslog {
        archive size 100k files 3;
        user * {
            any emergency;
        }
        file messages {
            any critical;
            authorization info;
        }
        file interactive-commands {
            interactive-commands error;
        }
    }
    max-configurations-on-flash 5;
    max-configuration-rollbacks 5;
    license {
        autoupdate {
            url https://ae1.juniper.net/junos/key_retrieval;
        }
    }
}
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/0 {
        unit 0;
    }
    ge-0/0/1 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode access;
                vlan {
                    members LAPTOPS;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/2 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode trunk;
                vlan {
                    members [ vlan-trust AREA0 ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/3 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode trunk;
                vlan {
                    members [ vlan-trust AREA1 ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/4 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode trunk;
                vlan {
                    members [ vlan-trust AREA2 ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/5 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                port-mode trunk;
                vlan {
                    members [ vlan-trust AREA3 ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/6 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/7 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/8 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/9 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/10 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/11 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/12 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/13 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/14 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/15 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    vlan {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.1.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 32 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.32.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 33 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.33.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 34 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.34.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 35 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.35.1/24;
            }
        }
        unit 36 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.36.1/24;
            }
        }
    }
}
routing-options {
    static {
        route 192.168.33.0/24 next-hop 192.168.33.2;
        route 192.168.208.0/24 next-hop 192.168.33.2;
    }
}
protocols {
    stp;
}
security {
    screen {
        ids-option untrust-screen {
            icmp {
                ping-death;
            }
            ip {
                source-route-option;
                tear-drop;
            }
            tcp {
                syn-flood {
                    alarm-threshold 1024;
                    attack-threshold 200;
                    source-threshold 1024;
                    destination-threshold 2048;
                    timeout 20;
                }
                land;
            }
        }
    }
    nat {
        source {
            rule-set trust-to-untrust {
                from zone trust;
                to zone untrust;
                rule source-nat-rule {
                    match {
                        source-address 0.0.0.0/0;
                    }
                    then {
                        source-nat {
                            interface;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    policies {
        from-zone trust to-zone untrust {
            policy trust-to-untrust {
                match {
                    source-address any;
                    destination-address any;
                    application any;
                }
                then {
                    permit;
                }
            }
        }
        from-zone Area to-zone Area {
            policy Area-to-Area {
                match {
                    source-address any;
                    destination-address any;
                    application any;
                }
                then {
                    permit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    zones {
        security-zone trust {
            host-inbound-traffic {
                system-services {
                    all;
                }
                protocols {
                    all;
                }
            }
            interfaces {
                vlan.0;
            }
        }
        security-zone untrust {
            screen untrust-screen;
            interfaces {
                ge-0/0/0.0 {
                    host-inbound-traffic {
                        system-services {
                            dhcp;
                            tftp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        security-zone Area {
            host-inbound-traffic {
                system-services {
                    all;
                }
            }
            interfaces {
                vlan.32;
                vlan.33;
                vlan.34;
                vlan.35;
                vlan.36;
                ge-0/0/1.0 {
                    host-inbound-traffic {
                        system-services {
                            ping;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ge-0/0/2.0;
                ge-0/0/3.0;
                ge-0/0/4.0;
                ge-0/0/5.0;
            }
        }
    }
}
vlans {
    AREA0 {
        vlan-id 33;
        l3-interface vlan.33;
    }
    AREA1 {
        vlan-id 34;
        l3-interface vlan.34;
    }
    AREA2 {
        vlan-id 35;
        l3-interface vlan.35;
    }
    AREA3 {
        vlan-id 36;
        l3-interface vlan.36;
    }
    LAPTOPS {
        vlan-id 32;
        l3-interface vlan.32;
    }
    vlan-trust {
        vlan-id 3;
        l3-interface vlan.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post configuration?

Comment: @BenjaminDale Config attached. My Desktop environment is called LAPTOPS and the Server environment called AREA(0,1,2,3).https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PNZ8TO4LoSzboDPTN60fIsAMMLP0N58yIw8MO7fGpOY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Post the configuration here please, so this question remains relevant after the document is removed from the linked website.

Comment: @TeunVink I initially tried this, and it stated I was over the limit by 8000+ characters. I am open to suggestions how to be able to paste the whole config here as requested.

Comment: I was able to paste the configuration without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I see a couple of odd things:

- You have a static route (192.168.33.0/24) to a host in the same directly attached subnet (vlan.33) - delete this.
- You also have L2 interfaces configured under your Area security zone (ge-0/0/1-5) delete these as well - security zones only require L3 interfaces.

If your servers are in the 192.168.208.0/24 range and on the other side of the Brocade, you will need to make sure that the Brocade has a static route pointing to the Laptop VLAN 192.168.32.0/24 with a next-hop of 192.168.33.1 for return traffic.

Comment: that was spot on! I added a static route pointing back to the laptop VLAN and can now ping the laptop from the Brocade. Although the laptop is still unable to ping the servers, I think this is down to the static route for 192.168.208.0/24 to 172.16.33.2 which is the gateway for VLAN 33 on the Brocade, I will change this to 172.16.33.1 instead which is the gateway on the Juniper for VLAN 33.